# Как заставить float вывести больше 15 знаков после запятой? Python

Tags: python, float

Пытаюсь вывести число ПИ из функции

```
...
return float(return_pi)
```

Но выдает только с 15-ю знаками после запятой. Можно ли вывести все знаки после запятой, оставив float?

Comment: Это невозможно, тип float физически не способен вместить в себя больше значащих знаков

Comment: @andreymal и, тем не менее, можно вот так `print(format(1/3, "0.55f"))`

Comment: @vitidev знаки в конце числа являются артефактом неточности вычислений и не несут в себе никакого смысла

Comment: Ну и сама фраза «все знаки» не имеет смысла, потому что при преобразовании двоичного float'а в десятичный человеческий вид зачастую получается бесконечная дробь с бесконечным числом знаков (в том числе и на вышеупомянутом примере 1/3)

Comment: @andreymal да понятно, что смысла не несут, но откуда то format их берет чтобы выводить. А он ведь получает на вход тот самый float

Comment: А ну и да, фраза «все знаки» по отношению к числу π ещё более бессмысленно, потому что это число иррациональное)

Answer (score 5):

Начнём с печати как можно большего количества знаков:

> ```
> $ python
> Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 16 2021, 12:17:56) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> @>>> import math
> @>>> f'{math.pi:.100g}'
> '3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875'
> ```

Обратите внимание - я попросил 100 знаков, а получил меньше. Питон отказывается печатать слишком много чепухи.

Дальше я напечатаю число типа `float` предшествующее `math.pi` и следующее за ним:

> ```
> @>>> prev = math.nextafter(math.pi, -math.inf)
> @>>> next = math.nextafter(math.pi, math.inf)
> @>>> f'{prev:.100g}'
> '3.141592653589792671908753618481568992137908935546875'
> @>>> f'{next:.100g}'
> '3.141592653589793560087173318606801331043243408203125'
> ```

Рассмотрим их внимательнее:

> ```
>           10        20
>   12345678901234567890
>                 v
> 3.141592653589792671908753618481568992137908935546875
> 3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875
> 3.141592653589793560087173318606801331043243408203125
> ```

Они начинают различаться на пятнадцатом знаке после запятой. Это значит что точности `float` хватает чтобы выписать только пятнадцать знаков после запятой, все цифры сверх того не имеют смысла. Хотя их можно напечатать, их нет в памяти. Их придумывает алгоритм, который переводит двоичный `float` в десятичный вид. К реальному значению числа они отношения не имеют.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за комментарии и Stanislav Volodarskiy за ответ. Изначально float я использовал потому что хотел получить тип "число", при этом получив все знаки в print. Но благодаря ответам понял, что это невозможно. Нашел такое решение:

```
import decimal
......

return decimal.Decimal(return_pi)
```

Работает

Comment: А зависимости от значения `return_pi` это решение может иметь или не иметь смысла — если `return_pi` это тот же самый float, то после 15 знаков всё равно будет бессмыслица

Comment: @andreymal, сейчас выяснится что `return_pi` - строка. Приготовится!